# What is the rest of the text in the Google search URL?

Tags: google-chrome, url, links

For example, when I search "superuser" on Google, the first part of the URL is https://www.google.com/search?q=superuser, but there's also some extra text following behind it. When I remove the extra text and I go to https://www.google.com/search?q=superuser, I still get the same results.

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

This blog post [Google Search URL Parameters [Ultimate Guide]](https://www.seoquake.com/blog/google-search-param/) explains the parameters used by Google Search. They are shown on the images below (the images have been copied from the same link).

> URL parameters are a set of values in the browser’s address bar after the website address. They start with a question mark and could go in a different order or be combined differently. Each URL parameter consists of a key=value pair. Multiple parameters are separated by the ampersand.
>
> URL parameters are generated automatically, but you can tailor them to your specific needs using Google Search Console settings. They solve many technical problems, such as:
>
> 1. User identification, working session facilitation, filling your online shopping cart.
> 2. Tracking landing page conversions.
> 3. Internal website search.
> 4. Filter items in online stores.
> 5. Sort items by price, brand, popularity.
> 6. Pagination of directories and multi-page content.
> 7. Displaying different page versions depending on the user language or country.

**URL search**
[image: URL search parameters]

**Content filtering options**
[image: Content filtering parameters]

**Language and Geolocation Parameters**

[image: Language and Geolocation parameters]

**Time Attributes**
[image: Time Attributes parameters]